# Find path to result nodes in PostgreSQL JSON

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

I'd like to execute jsonpath queries like `jsonb_path_query_all(..., '$.**.bar)` on

```json
{
  "foo": [
   { "xxx": 24 }
   { "bar": 42 }
  ]
}
```

but instead of getting only the result `[42]` I'd like to find all paths to results, so in this case it would be `[ ["foo", 1 ] ]`. Is there an efficient way to lookup value 'position' in a JSON?

In JS jsonpath there are methods like [jp.paths](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath#jppathsobj-pathexpression-count) or [jp.nodes](https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath#jpnodesobj-pathexpression-count) that do exactly this.

**EDIT**: Regrettably Postgres does not support the `$..bar` notation that many implementations of JSONPath support:

```
# SELECT jsonb_path_query('{"foo":{"bar":42}}'::jsonb, '$..bar');
ERROR:  syntax error, unexpected '.' at or near "." of jsonpath input
LINE 1: ...ECT jsonb_path_query('{"foo":{"bar":42}}'::jsonb, '$..bar');
```

Comment: I'm not sure about postgres, but `**` isn't valid in JSON Path.

Comment: There might be a configuration you need to set, or returning paths might not be supported.  Again, not sure about postgres.

Comment: @gregsdennis JSON Path is not really a standard, therefore the syntax differs: With JS the 'deep search' would use `$..bar`. For some reason the `**` notation in PostgreSQL is not well documented but it certainly works.

Comment: I'm aware of the status of JSON Path. I'm on the team that's [developing the standard](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base). There's also a [comparison project](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/) that runs common syntaxes across known implementations. `**` is not there.

Comment: I'm not blaming _you_ for this syntax.  Postgres shouldn't support it.  If a more "standard" or common notation works, I'd suggest use that.  There might be a reason it's not well-documented.

Comment: Agreed, I would also prefer if the syntax was unified. The *standard* way doesn't work, though (see edit). And my question is specific about PostgreSQL. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @gregsdennis: Postgres follows the SQL/JSON path syntax which does not define a "recursive operator". The extension/deviation from the SQL/JSON standard is [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#TYPE-JSONPATH-ACCESSORS): "*Recursive wildcard member accessor that processes all levels of the JSON hierarchy of the current object and returns all the member values, regardless of their nesting level. This is a PostgreSQL extension of the SQL/JSON standard.*"

Comment: @RadimVansa: the full syntax of the supported SQL/JSON path standard is documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#TYPE-JSONPATH-ACCESSORS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I was looking for that in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH but that does not mention it.

Comment: Btw. I've stumbled upon another difference: while PostgreSQL requires numeric array subscript (e.g. `foo[42]`), in JS JSON Path it's possible to use the subscript to access objects, too (for example `foo["bar 42"]` - in PostgreSQL I'd use `foo."bar 42"`).

Comment: @RadimVansa: this will be possible in Postgres 14. But again: the SQL standard for SQL/JSON is a separate standard and has nothing to do with things defined in the JavaScript world.